# MySQL count occurrences but return all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to count occurrences of *name*, but i want each row returned no matter if that name has already been counted. The data looks like;

```
ID |  NAME  
1     Peter 
2     Simone 
3     Otto
4     Cedric 
5     Peter 
6     Cedric
7     Cedric
```

The following only returns one row per unique name

```
select id, first_name, count(first_name)from table group by first_name

ID |  FIRST_NAME  | count(first_name)
1     Peter          2
2     Simone         1
3     Otto           1
4     Cedric         3
```

But im trying to return every row, something like

```
ID |  FIRST_NAME  | count(first_name)
1     Peter          2
2     Simone         1
3     Otto           1
4     Cedric         3
5     Peter          2
6     Cedric         3
7     Cedric         3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL version >= 8.0, then you can use window functions:

```
select id,
       first_name,
       count(*) over (partition by first_name)
from table
```

For earlier versions:

```
select id,
       first_name,
       (select count(*) from table where first_name = t.first_name)
from table t
```

Comment: Id seems rather meaningless in this context

Comment: @Strawberry OP included it in resultset, so who I am to change those requirements :)

Comment: i included "id" simply as an example as it was easier rather than real column name/data. so thanks for including in answer @MichalTurczyn, worked exactly as needed.

Comment: @olym If my answer has helped you,you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn im unable to upvote or accept answer due to being a newbie. Your solution is the easiest for my situation, however as fancyPants noted below, a correlated subquery might take a performance hit

Answer (score 1):

Edit: now that I've seen the other answers, why is joining better than using a correlated subquery? Because a correlated subquery is executed for every row in your table. When you join it, the query is executed just once.

---

Then you have to join those queries.

```
select * from
table 
inner join (
    select first_name, count(first_name) as name_count from table group by first_name
) qcounts on table.first_name = qcounts.first_name
```

Also note, that in your query you have to remove `id` from the select clause, since you neither have it in your group by clause nor do you apply an aggregate function on it. Therefore a random row is returned for this column.
It's a good idea to let MySQL remind you of that by activating the `only_full_group_by` sql mode. To do this you can do

```
set global sql_mode = concat(@@global.sql_mode, 'only_full_group_by');
```

Comment: I think you mean `table.first_name = qcounts.first_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.first_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) 
        FROM table t2 
        WHERE t2.first_name = t1.first_name) AS total_count
FROM table t1
```